# How to update/ overwrite input in the same row not in lastrow google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a search tool like this:

https://sites.google.com/site/appsscriptexperiments/home/a-simple-search-tool-ui

But put it in a panel, add an edit button to enable textboxes and an update button to save changes. But how will i update the existing data in the same row from which i have searched? Is it possible? Yes its updating but it returns to the last row. not in the same row.

```
function updatebutton(e){ 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('exampleID').getActiveSheet();

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();

  var row= ss.getDataRange().getRowIndex();

  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  var timestamp = e.timestamp = new Date() +  
  Session.getActiveUser().getUserLoginId();

  var txt0 = e.parameter.txt0;

  var txt1 = e.parameter.txt1;

  var txt2 = e.parameter.txt2;

  var txt3 = e.parameter.txt3;

  var data = ss.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1,4).setValues([[timestamp,txt1,txt2,txt3]]);

  return app;

}
```

Or is it possible to identify the Row from where i want to input the data? Little help will do. Thanks!

Also looking at ths one. but i can't get it right. http://quabr.com/28397927/how-to-update-a-google-worksheet-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

you can call the method "getActiveCell()" and from there you can get the column and row of the active cell, here is the [doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getActiveCell()).

Comment: What if it will just submit to the lastRow+1 and delete the existing data that i've searched?

Comment: The method getActiveCell will return a range object with then information of the active cell, you can then set the value, so if you want to delete the data you would set empty values.  Then you would get the range of lastRow+1 ans set the information you want.  If that is not what you meant then please be clear.